# dealloc MPMoviePlayer before new instance is being created

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

My App is dynamically allocating and instantiating the MPMoviePlayer class. The problem: when a second instance is being created while the first is still playing a video the app is crashing.

```
Error: *** Assertion failure in -[MPMoviePlayerClassNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:], /SourceCache/MediaPlayer/MobileMusicPlayer-2770.3.5/SDK/MPMoviePlayerClass.m:1385
Exception: movie player <MPMoviePlayerControllerNew: 0x0000000> has wrong activation state (1)
```

I'm currently just using a @try-@catch for avoiding a crash.

Because it's dynamically being called to instantiate I can't dealloc the existing MPMoviePlayer itself in the class.

Is there any possibility to deallocate all objects of a class before it's creating a new instance? Or Do you know any other solutions for my problem?

Comment: Please share some code so we can actually help properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't want to have two videos playing at the same time. You should create a manager to handle the playback and the transition from one file to another.

You would create a single instance of the video manager object and create an api like

```
-(BOOL)startPlayback:(NSString *)path;
```

The manager could also handle the output view etc.

Right now, you're using it wrong ;)